# Ionic: unable to archive app in xcode8.2.1 but it build successfully

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

I am new with ionic1 framework. Currently i am working on ionic sidemenu ios app. I have create a share extention its working fine and build my app on iphone but when i archive it gives error

swift compiler error
 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found

failed to import bridging header '/Users/ht/msbsocial/myApp/platforms/ios/project/Bridging-Header.h'

I am not able to understand how to resolve it. I have searched and tried solutions but no luck. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To Archive a app in xcode you need to plug in a device, select it like if you would run the app on it, then you can archive it.

Comment: Yes i have plugged in device than archive.. but it gives same error.

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't been active for a long time, but...maybe this will be helpful to someone who gets the same problem in the future...

I had the same problem(build succeeded but archive failed) when I added an extension plugin`(cordova-plugin-call-directory)` to my ionic project. I solved the problem by:

`select extension under [Targets]` >> `go to [Build Settings]` >> `find [Objective-C Bridging Header]` >> `delete the path value` >> `clean and then archive`